# What is the difference between an AMP component and an AMP element as it relates to amp-story?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

What is the difference between an AMP component and an AMP element as it relates to amp-story?

> Components. **AMP components in** action. Learn how to build AMPs using the built-in components. https://ampbyexample.com/#components
>
> The amp-sidebar should be a direct child of the `<body>`. It must have a layout of nodisplay. The amp-sidebar may not contain any **AMP Elements** except for amp-accordion, amp-img and amp-fit-text. amp-fit-text expands or shrinks its font size to fit the content within the space given to in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "AMP components" and "AMP elements" are synonyms.